# I have installed kde plasma on Ubuntu 20.10 but after I logged out, there is no option to login back to kde. What can I do to have kde back?

Tags: command-line

Which command can I execute to get back to kde plasma from ubuntu's terminal? Thanks

Comment: On the GDM login screen, click on your user name. Before entering the password, in the bottom right of the GDM screen, click on the gear icon. When you click this, do you see an option for KDE?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have incomplete installation of KDE Plasma.

The complete set of packages is provided by the `kubuntu-desktop` task package.

To install it use command below:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^
```

then confirm `sddm` login manager selection, reboot and login to Plasma.